# Understanding type signature for the take function

Tags: haskell

```
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
```

`(Num i , Ord i)` means class constraint

`i -> [a]`  means this two is belong to class constraint

`last [a]` mean's output.

is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand what you're asking.  If you just want to know what the type signature means, you can break it down as:

```
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
-- ^--- The function named "take'"
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
--    ^--- Has type
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
--        ^--- Constrained where "i" implements "Num" and "Ord"
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
--                         ^--- The first argument has type "i"
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
--                              ^--- The second argument has type "[a]"
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
--  The return value has type "[a]" ---^
```

So in one sentence, the function `take'` has two arguments, the first argument must be a `Num` and an `Ord`, the second argument must be a list of any type, and the return value has the same type as the second argument.

Comment: thanks for answering my question. you mentioned that i implements "Num" and "Ord". how about the second argument has type "[a]".it is also implements "Num" and "Ord"

Comment: @user3222659 The constraints of the type signature only apply to the type variable `i`, since it says `(Num i, Ord i)`, `a` does not appear in there anywhere.  If you wanted `a` to implement `Num` and `Ord` (which I would assume to be completely unnecessary for this function), you could do `take' :: (Num i, Ord i, Num a, Ord a) => i -> [a] -> [a]`

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the implementation I can only comment on the type signature.

Constraint part you got right. It's a type class constraints where `i` must have a `Num` and `Ord` instance.

```
(Num i , Ord i) =>
```

The second part is a a function of two variables from an ordered numeric value `i` to a list of polymorphic types of `a` to a list of the same type `a`.

```
i -> [a] -> [a]
```

An implementation of this function might look like:

```
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
take' n _ | n <= 0 = []
take' _ [] =  []
take' n (x:xs) =  x : take' (n-1) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

`(Num i, Ord i)` means that everywhere in the type signature of the function `i` is a member of the `Num` class and the `Ord` class.  These are, rather obviously, short for number and order.  Here are their definitions.

```
class Num a where
   (+), (*), (-) :: a -> a -> a
   negate :: a -> a
   abs :: a -> a
   signum :: a -> a
   fromInteger :: Integer -> a

class Eq a => Ord a where
   compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
   (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
   (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
   (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
   (<=) :: a -> a -> Bool
   max :: a -> a -> a
   min :: a -> a -> a
```

So what does this all mean.  Well, it means for every type that is an instance of this class the following functions can be used with that type.  For the `Num` class these are basic operations that you would expect to be able to apply to a number.  Notice the lack of division.  Because `Int` and `Integer` are a type of `Num` there is no division because if you divide by something that is not divisible then you end up with a non integral type.  This is why there are more type classes to handle this, such as `Fractional`.

The `Ord` class provides functions for ordering values of certain types.  This allows people to compare values and form some sort of logical ordering of values.

The type signature chosen is a bit strange though as I would think

`take' :: Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]`

Would make more sense.